# Arduino doesn't read a proper amount of bytes

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino, usb, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to Arduino Mega with USB and trying to send a 8-byte package from RPI to Arduino. I'm using WiringPi serial library to accomplish this.
RPI part scans serial buffer for data available. If not, it writes data to serial.

```
for(;;) {
    if (int i = serialDataAvail(f_)) {
       printf("RPI received %d bytes\n", i);
       uint8_t buf[i];
       read(f_, buf, i);
       printf("%s",buf);
    }
    ..some code filling variable widthsChar with data...
    write(f_, widthsChar, sizeof(widthsChar));
    printf("amount sent: %d \n", sizeof(widthsChar));
    usleep(3000000); //3 sec;
}
```

And here comes an Arduino part which waits for RPI data to arrive and responds with a number of bytes received.

```
while(Serial.available() == 0);
String bytesNum = String(Serial.available());
String newString = "Arduino received " + bytesNum + " bytes\n";
Serial.print(newString);
delay(10000);
```

I guess, the output is supposed to be something like this:

```
amount sent: 8
//waits for 3 sec
RPI received 25 bytes
Arduino received 8 bytes
amount sent: 8
//and so far
```

What I get in reality is not something I can explain and asking for someone to help to understand it.
Here it goes:

```
amount sent: 8
//nothings happens for 3 sec
amount sent: 8
RPI received 25 bytes
Arduino received 1 bytes
W??1??0mount sent: 8
// I tried to interpret random chars it displays that way
//and so far
```

Comment: `uint8_t buf[i];` - i don't know how this compiles, since `i` isn't constant. You need dynamic allocation.

Comment: I believe it creates a uint8_t array of i elements each iteration which destroys after end of iteration. I don't see why it shouldn't compile.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in VS2013, neither in separate scope.

Comment: Oh, sorry - it indeed works if you declare it in `if` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing lies in the actual timeline of events.

When the RPi sends the data to the Arduino, remember that it is sending it *serially*, i.e. one character at a time.

As soon as the first byte of data arrives at the Arduino, then Serial.available() will return 1, indicating that the first byte has arrived! Your code then goes to work to process only that first byte (the Arduino is much faster than the serial communication).

An easy solution is to use [Serial.readBytes()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadBytes), which will keep reading the bytes until the RPi stops sending, and buffer them up for you. It will keep reading the bytes until the serial timeout is achieved (default:1 second), or until the buffer is filled up.

```
while(Serial.available() == 0)
    ; // Waiting for data

char buffer[80];
int bytesRead = Serial.readBytes(buffer, 80);

String msg = "Arduino received ";
msg += bytesRead;
msg += " bytes";
Serial.println(msg);
delay(10000);
```

The problem with the RPi printing out garbage characters on the last line is likely a different, seperate issue.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I've figured this out already, the answer is indeed correct.